# How to filter JSON array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I currently have this `LEFT JOIN` which is part of a bigger select

```
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    tags_components.component_id,
    array_to_json(array_agg(tags.*)) as tags
    FROM tags_components
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_components.tag_id AND tags_components.component_name = 'contact'
    GROUP BY tags_components.component_id
) AS tags ON tags.component_id = contact.id
```

Which works as expected if component has all tags assigned. However `tags` array is always of size `COUNT(tags.*)` so for component without any tags is filled with `null`. Is there a way how filter those nulls out? I tried different things like using `json_strip_nulls` or having `FILTER` on the array but I didn't achieve the right result (JSON array containing only non-nulls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly then the issue you face is in the line:

```
...
array_to_json(array_agg(tags.*)) as tags
...
```

Maybe you used `FILTER` in a wrong way, but this does work to eliminta `NULL` results like:

```
SELECT  array_to_json(
            -- FILTER is applied to this specific 'array_agg'
            array_agg( t.* ) FILTER ( WHERE t.tag IS NOT NULL )
        )
FROM    ( VALUES
            ( 'a1' ),
            ( 'b1' ),
            ( null ),
            ( 'c1' ),
            ( null ),
            ( 'd1' )
        ) t( tag );

-- Resolves to:
                     array_to_json
-------------------------------------------------------
 [{"tag":"a1"},{"tag":"b1"},{"tag":"c1"},{"tag":"d1"}]
(1 row)
```

Alternatively you can use `jsonb_agg` (read more at [Postgres Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html)) instead of `array_to_json + array_agg` to provide same result like:

```
SELECT  jsonb_agg( t.* ) FILTER ( WHERE t.tag IS NOT NULL )
FROM    ( VALUES
            ( 'a1' ),
            ( 'b1' ),
            ( null ),
            ( 'c1' ),
            ( null ),
            ( 'd1' )
        ) t( tag );
```

Comment: Thank you, the filter really worked. I would bet I wrote exactly the same code but apparently not :)

Answer (score 2):

array_remove function is going to be your best bet now: 
`array_to_json(array_remove(array_agg(tags.*), null)) as tags`